# Como mapear uma imagem para funcionar responsivo

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagem

Tenho uma imagem de uma cama e precisava que quando o mouse hover acontecesse no travesseiro subisse um popup, porém não sei um modo de mapear essa imagem, eu ia utilizar map do html porém não terei responsividade, alguém sabe um modo de fazer com que o travesseiro fique com hover? obs: A parte do popup sei fazer somente quero saber como identificar que o travesseiro disparou hover, abaixo uma imagem explicando

[image: Hover em travesseiros]

Comment: Uma alternativa é criar uma div do tamanho travesseiro, rotaciona-la de acordo e coloca-la encima do travesseiro com position:absolute e opacidade no máximo, caso não saiba como fazer, fala aqui que quando possível monto um exemplo...

Comment: Sim @FelipeDuarte mais eu não estava querendo usar o absolute pois como ela irá se mater em cima do travesseiro em qualquer resolução?

Comment: Depende da responsividade, ao diminuir a tela, a imagem vai manter suas dimensões ou vai diminuir também? se não o absolute já serve, se sim creio que é possível fazer aninhado, mas só testando para saber.

Comment: Eu irei testar com o absolute